# Leak in my disc brakes

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

I had a small crash and the other day I checked my bike for damage. I found that there is very small leak on my brake hose where it meets the lever.

I tried pushing the lever but nothing came out so can it leak only for one day and then it stops?

My brakes are Shimano BR-MT200.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You do not want your brakes to fail when you need them. If it is perforated, it should be inspected by someone experienced. Too much air in the system and instead of moving the pistons you will be just compressing the air.

Comment: Is the lever spongy, and are you sure the fluid was not there before the crash?

Comment: im not sure if the fluid was there before the crash  and the lever feels the same as my other brake

Comment: I have an old english car - when it stops leaking, is because its run out and needs refilling!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely do not want to ignore this. Loss of brake function is obviously dangerous.

At the very least, check regularly for further leaks in this area, before and after you ride. You mat find that the leak re-occurs after a while even though you cannot replicate it by squeezing the lever a few times.

You can of course have a repair shop look at it. Checking the hose for damage and replacing the bolt, olive and insert is probably a good idea.

Comment: the problem is that there are no "experienced" bike shop at my town and the only possible thing to do is to ship back the bike to the shop i got it from and they could check it

Comment: Posting a clear high resolution picture of the area where the leak occurred may help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/aurrqwY the fluid is where the black hose meets the gray metal thing

Comment: No evidence of impact on the lever or hose. Make sure the nut is tightened to correct torque and keep an eye on it. If it leaks again or you feel brake performance diminishing have it looked at.

Comment: the leak is so small that on camera you cant see but its there i can see it shine a bit anyways thanks alot ill talk with some expert and if it happen againg ill have it looked